# SQL query to update a column value using a select query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have tables as below:

Language

```
language_id   | language_name 
--------------------
   1             English
   2             Hindi
```

Book

```
 book_id   | language_id  | book_name
---------------------------------
   1             1            Head First Java
   2             1            Head First C
   3             2            Head First Java
   4             2            Head First C
```

Student

```
 student_id   | language_id  |  book_id
--------------------------------------
   1             1                1
   2             2                3
```

Now, I have to update the `book_id` column of `Student` table,  with `id` value of another book where the current `book_name = Head First Java`, new `book_name = Head First C` and the new book must be of same language.

Sample Result:

```
student_id   | language_id  |  book_id
--------------------------------------
   1             1                2
   2             2                4
```

I am facing issues to write a T-SQL query to do this. Please help me on this.

Comment: Is there any condition to update?

Comment: So you want to know how to write an `UPDATE`-Statement in SQL-Server?

Comment: yes, I have mentioned the conditions in the question. Current book name should be Head First Java, new one should be Head First C and the language of both books should be same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you need to use an alias for update, to find the right language in the setting subquery.

```
update s
set s.book_id = (select book_id from book 
                 where book_name = 'Head First C'
                and language_id = s.language_id)
from student s
where s.book_id in (select book_id from book where book_name = 'Head First Java')
```

Comment: I guess, you need to update the language id as well.

Comment: @AT-2016 no. You have to keep the language.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass any condition like this.

```
 update Student set book_id = 2 where book_id = 1
```

**OR**

```
 update Student set book_id = 2 where book_id = 1 and student_id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try it, It should address your requirement

```
UPDATE s SET s.book_id = b.book_id
FROM [language] l
INNER JOIN (SELECT language_id, 
                MAX(book_id) book_id 
            FROM book 
            GROUP BY language_id ) b ON b.language_id = l.language_id 
INNER JOIN student s ON s.language_id = b.language_id
```